# CKModifyBadgeOperation crashes for no reason

Tags: ios, swift2, cloudkit

I have created a subscription for insert & it sends push notification as follows

```
let subscriptionNotification = CKNotificationInfo()

subscriptionNotification.alertBody = "New Book has been created by Author"

subscriptionNotification.shouldBadge = true

subscription.notificationInfo = subscriptionNotification
```

When I receive the notification I open the app & I am simply trying to reset badge to zero

```
let resetBadge = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: 0)

    resetBadge.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = {(error) in

        if error != nil {

            print(error)

        }
        else {

            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        }

    }

    CKContainer.defaultContainer().addOperation(resetBadge)
```

I run this code on appdelegate did finish launching with options method.
I get following error. Keep in mind the name of the project is **ckreference demo**.

> 2015-12-15 21:41:58.417 ckreference demo[2486:1478837] -[CKNotification queryNotificationReason]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15cd8a960
>   2015-12-15 21:41:58.427 ckreference demo[2486:1478837] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CKNotification queryNotificationReason]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15cd8a960'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x183521900 0x182b8ff80 0x18352861c 0x1835255b8 0x18342968c 0x1000b8b9c 0x1000b9250 0x1884cbae4 0x1884b9de0 0x184ad7790 0x184ad7b10 0x1834d8efc 0x1834d8990 0x1834d6690 0x183405680 0x184914088 0x18827cd90 0x1000b94d0 0x182fa68b8)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Any suggestions on how to stop app from crashing?

The crash happens here

[image]

Comment: Update your question with your code that is calling `queryNotificationReason`. It would seem your code is making an assumption that a `CKNotification` is a `CKQueryNotification` when it really isn't.

Comment: I am not calling any CKQueryNotification. I have commented that part. It does not run. Also I didn't receive any notification & there was no unread notification in queue.

Comment: Then update your question with the relevant portion of the symbolicated stack trace so we can see where the crash is happening.

Comment: I updated the question. Is this what you wanted? <+204> is where app crashes

Comment: Not really. There should be a more readable stack trace showing where the crash it actually happening.

Comment: I have updated question with exact screenshot. But my question is "Do I have the right code?" I couldn't find proper tutorial on CKModifyBadgeOperation. I used one from Stack overflow question. All I want to do is reset badge to zero when I open the app.

Comment: That's not useful either. That still doesn't show where the app really crashes. Perhaps you should see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1